# Delete files via powershell for time

Tags: powershell

I need to delete files created more than 1 hour ago, how can I do this with PowerShell?

I found several links showing the exclusion by days (Get-Date), but none based on time

Comment: There's plenty of Google articles you can find regarding this, plenty. The most common scenario is using `(Get-Date).AddHours(-1)` for time an hour ago, and the rest is logic on how to proceed. Such as `if ($Modtime -ge $Time){...`

Comment: A DateTime object has a [AddHours()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addhours) method

Answer (score 0):

I've already found a solution here:

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\temp | 
    Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (date).AddMinutes(-1440)} |
        Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: 1440 minutes ==> 24 hours ==> 1 day. Your question is about _"older than 1 hour"_..